# Unable to change header title via headertext

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to edit my gridview header title  however, unfortunately it doesn't work

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = project; Integrated Security= SSPI";
conn.Open();

DataSet ds = new DataSet();

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT policeid, password, email, nric, fullname, contact, address, location From LoginRegisterPolice where pending='pending'", conn);
da.Fill(ds);

GVVerify.DataSource = ds;
GVVerify.DataBind();
GVVerify.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Police ID ";
GVVerify.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Password";
GVVerify.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Email ";
GVVerify.Columns[4].HeaderText = "NRIC ";
GVVerify.Columns[5].HeaderText = "Full Name ";
GVVerify.Columns[6].HeaderText = "Contact ";
GVVerify.Columns[7].HeaderText = "Address ";
GVVerify.Columns[8].HeaderText = "Location ";

conn.Close();
```

This is the error i received

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection.

I have checked that my column index is not negative and it's the correct column number as well. I have added `allowgenerateselectbutton` in my gridview. Therefore, i started it with 1-8 instead of 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by simply using column alias in your select SQL, no need to do it from code.

```
SELECT policeid as [Police ID] , password as [Password] ...............
```

Answer (score 1):

The columns property is a zero based array. Unless there is a hidden first column you are starting at 1. Re-number the indices to 0-7 instead of 1-8.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columns(v=vs.80).aspx

```
    GVVerify.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Police ID ";
    GVVerify.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Password";
    GVVerify.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Email ";
    GVVerify.Columns[3].HeaderText = "NRIC ";
    GVVerify.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Full Name ";
    GVVerify.Columns[5].HeaderText = "Contact ";
    GVVerify.Columns[6].HeaderText = "Address ";
    GVVerify.Columns[7].HeaderText = "Location ";
```

Comment: i added allowgenerateselectbutton in my gridview. Therefore, i started it with 1-8 instead of 0.

Comment: Can you post the results of the following query: `GVVerify.Columns[7].HeaderText;` get it from the debugger. Do it before you change the header values.

Comment: I'm not sure why i cant debug it. I select the code with the red circle beside it. Runs the project then select step over but there's no query :/

Comment: Try using `Debug.Print(GVVerify.Columns[7].HeaderText);` then watch the output window during execution

Answer (score 0):

You have to try from `Index 0` or try different approach like

```
GVVerify.Columns[0].HeaderText  = "Police ID ";
------------------------------------
--------------------------------------

or

GVVerify.Columns["columnname"].HeaderText  = "Police ID ";
------------------
-------------------
```